# Cordova Firebase: Use keys for devevelopment and for production

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic2

I'm using this plugin https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase and it's working perfectly for me but since I have two apps in my Firebase console (one for dev purposes and the other one for production) I want to know if there is a way to have the two **google-services.json** files of each environment  in the same project and change between them when I'm compiling for dev or for prod.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cordova **hook** to replace *google-service.json* file with DEV o PROD file, trigged **onprebuild**

For more info on hook take a look here:
[Cordova Hook](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html)